# Django/React - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, json, django, reactjs

I'm having an error running the webpack dev script, [this is the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2byQ3.png)

This are the codes:

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import DataProvider from "./DataProvider";
import Table from "./Table";
import Form from "./Form";

const App = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <DataProvider endpoint="api/lead/" 
                  render={data => <Table data={data} />} />
    <Form endpoint="api/lead/" />
  </React.Fragment>
);

const wrapper = document.getElementById("app");

wrapper ? ReactDOM.render(<App />, wrapper) : null;
```

package.json

```
 {
  "name": "amazona_project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development ./amazona/frontend/src/index.js --output ./amazona/frontend/static/frontend/main.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ./amazona/frontend/src/index.js --output ./amazona/frontend/static/frontend/main.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "webpack": "^4.25.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "description": ""
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

I'm sure the problem has something to do with the syntax, but I dont understand which part is wrong in my code. I would really appreaciate the help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have `.babelrc` file in your project?

Comment: Did you try putting "react" in "presets" instead of "@babel/preset-react" ?

Comment: @RajendrakumarVankadari Tried that now, didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You will need to setup a .babelrc file and webpack.config.js

The .babelrc file should contain

```
{
 "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

The webpack.config.js should contain

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
   rules: [
     {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
         loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

You can use this link as reference in setting up your project

https://www.valentinog.com/blog/react-webpack-babel/#How_to_set_up_React_webpack_and_Babel_setting_up_the_project

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I forgot to add those codes, i will do that now, but i had those files allready set up. They are exactly as you typed, but the error's still there. Do you have any idea what other thing could be the issue?

Comment: did you try rerunning the build?